# Parse query string filter/sorting passed in JQuery style

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-datasource

Does anyone know of a standard library (or model binder) in C# to parse JQuery-style serialized filters (and sorting), like the one passed from the Kendo DataSource?

So to parse a query string like this to strongly typed array(s) with filter and sort objects:

```
sort[0][field]=status.name&sort[0][dir]=desc&filter[logic]=and&filter[filters][0][field]=status.name&filter[filters][0][operator]=eq&filter[filters][0][value]=Sold
```

I've tried searching but I mostly seem to run into incomplete implementations or JavaScript samples unfortunately.

**UPDATE:** I didn't realise this format is already standard supported until @Lali pointed out this is standard body form serialization.

I solved it now by creating some classes and just using this as parameter for the web API action, and it just magically works:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] ListSelectionOptionsWithFilter options)
{
   //query something
}

public class ListSelectionOptionsWithFilter
{
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Take { get; set; }
    public List<ListSortOption> Sort { get; set; }
    public ListFilterOptions Filter { get; set; }
}

public class ListFilterOptions
{
    public string Logic { get; set; }
    public List<ListFilterOption> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class ListFilterOption
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ListSortOption
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pass this data in body of request rather than sending in query string. You can have all the things in in single object if namings matched. Am I getting you right?

Comment: @Lali well I prefer to keep it a GET request, and that shouldn't have a body right? But you did give me the idea to just use the form body parser, let me check that, thanks!

Comment: I am doing it 'BaseController' by parsing request and puting all the parameters in an object and making that object accessible in all the controllers (Inheriting BaseController). Just an idea.

Comment: @Lali thanks for the pointer, I've updated the question.

Comment: You got the answer of your question from my hints but I am little confused.  Will it parse to object if all the data is sent using query string? (I mean you are using get request?)

Comment: @Lali Yup! It works because of the [FromUri] attribute. It uses the same parsing logic as form-encoded fields in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise this format is already standard supported until @Lali pointed out this is standard body form serialisation.

I solved it now by creating some classes and just using this as parameter for the web API action, and it just magically works:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri] ListSelectionOptionsWithFilter options)
{
   //query something
}

public class ListSelectionOptionsWithFilter
{
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Take { get; set; }
    public List<ListSortOption> Sort { get; set; }
    public ListFilterOptions Filter { get; set; }
}

public class ListFilterOptions
{
    public string Logic { get; set; }
    public List<ListFilterOption> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class ListFilterOption
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ListSortOption
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}
```